# Arquillian and Wildfly: Unable to collect/resolve dependency

Tags: java, maven, containers, wildfly, jboss-arquillian

I'm trying to write a simple Widlfly container test using Arquillian framework. I have followed the guide from [Wildfly container testing guide](https://howto.wildfly-swarm.io/test-in-container/).

The resulting pom.xml looks like follows.

**pom.xml**

```
<dependencyManagement>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.wildfly.swarm</groupId>
            <artifactId>bom-all</artifactId>
            <version>${version.wildfly-swarm}</version>
            <type>pom</type>
            <scope>import</scope>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
</dependencyManagement>

<dependencies>
    <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.hibernate.javax.persistence/hibernate-jpa-2.1-api -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.hibernate.javax.persistence</groupId>
        <artifactId>hibernate-jpa-2.1-api</artifactId>
        <version>1.0.2.Final</version>
        <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.mycompany.libs</groupId>
        <artifactId>3ds-commons</artifactId>
        <version>${project.version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>javax</groupId>
        <artifactId>javaee-api</artifactId>
        <version>8.0</version>
        <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>

    <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.mysema.querydsl/querydsl-apt -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.mysema.querydsl</groupId>
        <artifactId>querydsl-apt</artifactId>
        <version>3.7.4</version>
    </dependency>

    <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.mysema.querydsl/querydsl-jpa -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.mysema.querydsl</groupId>
        <artifactId>querydsl-jpa</artifactId>
        <version>3.7.4</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>junit</groupId>
        <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
        <version>4.12</version>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.wildfly.swarm</groupId>
        <artifactId>jaxrs</artifactId>
        <version>${version.wildfly-swarm}</version>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.wildfly.swarm</groupId>
        <artifactId>datasources</artifactId>
        <version>${version.wildfly-swarm}</version>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.wildfly.swarm</groupId>
        <artifactId>arquillian-adapter</artifactId>
        <version>${version.wildfly-swarm}</version>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.jboss.arquillian.junit</groupId>
        <artifactId>arquillian-junit-container</artifactId>
        <version>1.4.0.Final</version>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.wildfly.swarm</groupId>
        <artifactId>arquillian</artifactId>
        <version>${version.wildfly-swarm}</version>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.jboss.arquillian.core</groupId>
        <artifactId>arquillian-core-api</artifactId>
        <version>1.4.0.Final</version>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>
```

I was following the guide and wrote the JUnit test as follows.

**InContainerTest.java**

```
@RunWith(Arquillian.class)
@DefaultDeployment(type = DefaultDeployment.Type.JAR)
public class InContainerTest {

    @ArquillianResource
    InitialContext context;

    @Test
    public void testDataSourceIsBound() throws Exception {
        DataSource ds = (DataSource) context.lookup("java:jboss/datasources/MyDS");
        assertNotNull(ds);
    }
}
```

Whenever I try to run `mvn clean install` on this code, I'm getting the following error:

org.jboss.arquillian.container.spi.client.container.DeploymentException: Unable to collect/resolve dependency tree for a resolution due to: Failed to collect dependencies at my.company.libs:my-commons:jar:0.0.1-SNAPSHOT, caused by: Server returned HTTP response code: 409 for URL: http://repo.gradle.org/gradle/libs-releases-local/com/mycompany/libs/my-commons/0.0.1-SNAPSHOT/my-commons-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.pom

Package `my-commons` comes from the internal repository of my company, but we have Maven's `settings.xml` configured for it, and it normally works in all other cases.

Any help on this would be highly appreciated.

Comment: It looks like `my.company.libs:my-commons:jar:0.0.1-SNAPSHOT` is not in your repository.

Answer (score 0):

Please check if the "my-commons" actually contains snapshots or only release artifacts. check if there is some other repo for snapshots and adapt you maven configuration accordingly.  See here for reference how to do that: https://maven.apache.org/settings.html#Repositories